# Bathroom sink not fitting flush tailpipe was cut

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink

Bathroom sink and faucet was replaced .Tail pipe was long cut it shorter but sink won't sit flush withcounter
When I install flange and tail piece from above rather than on topsink is flush. I am clueless at to what I need?It fits when installed differently.  Never did this work before .Is there a correct way of installing this?

Comment: A picture is worth 1000 words. Please [edit] to include a picture of the plumbing below the sink. Of note, though, you should install the sink, _then_ and only then do you begin installing the plumbing underneath. You mention that the tail piece was too long and you cut it - you might need to cut it again. But... without pics that's only a random guess.